# Error: request for member ‘check’ in something not a structure or union

Tags: c

I am trying to implement this function in my code

```
Check QUEUEdelete_check(Q q, int refc){

 link *temp;
 *temp = q->head;
 if(temp->check.refc == refc)
    q->head = temp->next;
    free(temp);
    return temp->check;

 while(temp->next != NULL){
    if (temp->next->check.refc == refc){
        temp->next = temp->next->next;
        if(temp->next == NULL)
            q->tail = temp;
    free(temp->next);
    return temp->check;
    }
    temp = temp->next;
 }
 printf("Cheque %ld does not exist", refc); }
```

It gives me this error:

> Queue.c: In function ‘QUEUEdelete_check’:
>    Queue.c:49:12: error: request for member ‘check’ in something not a structure  or union

and also for the next

> Queue.c:50:23: error: request for member ‘next’ in something not a structure or union q->head = temp->next; 
>       if(temp->check.refc == refc)

The structs I'm using are:

```
typedef struct queue{ link head; link tail;} *Q; 
typedef struct node{Check check ;struct node *next; } *link;
typedef struct Check{long int amount, refe, refb, refc;}Check;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
typedef struct node{Check check ;struct node *next; } *link;
```

So, `link` is a pointer to `node`.

```
link *temp;
```

`temp` is a pointer to `link`, or pointer to pointer to node.

```
 if(temp->check.refc == refc)
```

This can also be written as `(*temp).check.refc`. `(*temp)` is a pointer to node, but you are accessing it with `.` which is reserved for structs and unions.

You need to either to `(*temp)->check.refc` or (much preferred) refactor your code to not use those pesky double pointers.